# Listbox in main window

Tags: c++, winapi, listbox

I'm creating a Win32 GUI application using Code::Blocks and MinGW.  I am using [this tutorial](http://www.winprog.org/tutorial/) as a guide.  Everything worked well until I decided I needed a listbox to display files in the current directory.  I don't want the list box in a window by itself, I want it inside the main window.  The tutorial I was following wasn't very helpful on this part, so I still don't know how to create a listbox.  Using the resource editor somehow, I think.  Could someone please help me?

Comment: Do you have Petzold's book, Programming Windows? If not, why not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you have a window procedure somewhere (let's call it `WndProc`) for your main window (let's call it `hWndMain`).

Add a `WM_CREATE` handler in `WndProc` if it's not already there.

In the `WM_CREATE` handler, add a call to `CreateWindowEx` to create the listbox as a child window of `hWndMain`:

```
const HWND hWndList = CreateWindowEx(...);
```

The picky parameters of `CreateWindowEx` that are essential here are the class name "LISTBOX", that the style parameter must include the `WS_CHILD` flag (plus the other essential listbox flags, of course) and that the parent parameter must be `hWndMain`.

For the other parameters, use your brain and read the docs.

Comment: Strange I didn't see your answer until now.  I had actually already worked this out before I read what you posted.  Thanks anyway!